# multiple belongs_to models in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a comments model that is currently working with Articles.  I would now like to have users be able to comment on the Coffeeshop reviews.  Am I able to use the same comment table, or should I have a separate one (feels janky).  I've not long been building with RoR (a few weeks) so still trying to get the hang of the basics.

Would I nest them in routes.rb (and how)

```
  resources :coffeeshops do
  resources :articles do
    resources :comments
  end
```

or

```
  resources :coffeeshops do
    resources :comments
  end

  resources :articles do
    resources :comments
  end
```

My models look like:

*User*

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
has_many :comments
end
```

*Comments*

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :article
  belongs_to :coffeeshop
end
```

*Articles*

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
end
```

*Coffeeshops*

```
class Coffeeshop < ApplicationRecord
has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
```

I'm then assuming I need a foreign key to tie the user and comments together, and then also the comments to the article/coffeeshop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd use a polymorphic association.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :comments
end

class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
end

class Article < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable
end

class Coffeeshop < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable
end
```

For some more information about setting up the routes/controller:

https://rubyplus.com/articles/3901-Polymorphic-Association-in-Rails-5
http://karimbutt.github.io/blog/2015/01/03/step-by-step-guide-to-polymorphic-associations-in-rails/

Comment: @SimonCooper: yep. With `as: :commentable`, of course.

Comment: Like Sergio already mentioned; yes. I've edited the answer to include the User model.

Comment: Seen the links for the routes too. Thanks.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev If a user writes the comments on articles or coffeeshops, `as: :commentable` is not necessary on `User`. The user owns the comment with user_id, and comments on a 'commentable' (Article or Coffeeshop)

Comment: @Laurens: ah, you're right, of course. Sorry about that. I thought user is just another commentable.

Comment: Ah! a perfect example where we can use polymorphic association.

Comment: @SimonCooper Could you please accept the answer if it helped you ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use comment model for both comments for articles and coffeeshops, but (because by default rails uses ids as primary and foreign keys I assume you use ids too) you will have to add column to comments table, where you set the comment type (You can create Enumerator in comment model, where you set 2 possible value types, each for article and coffeeshop models). If you don't add the column it will result in weird, hard to track bug where you can see comments for article on coffeeshop with same id and vise-versa.

UPD: he's little guide on using enums for rails models: http://www.justinweiss.com/articles/creating-easy-readable-attributes-with-activerecord-enums/ you will have to use it not in actual add comment form, but behind the scenes.

Comment: Ok that makes sense.  Currently my comments table as a 'article_id' column. Would I add a new column for 'coffeeshop_id'? Or have a column that says comment type, with values being one of article or coffeeshop?

Comment: You probably want to use polymorphic association in this case. In your table you basically have commented_resource_id as integer, and type (processed by enum in model, but in table is integer too). And then you want to set 'polymorphic: true' in you belongs_to relation. Actually, here's another guide that helped me to figure this out: https://launchschool.com/blog/understanding-polymorphic-associations-in-rails